# How to play vimeo Video by using official library Vimeo Networking Library?

Tags: android-studio, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I want to play the Vimeo video in my android app by using Vimeo Official library : [Vimeo networking library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) with the help of **VideoView or ExoPlayer**

The basic requirements for native playback are:

User must be logged in.
User must be the owner of the video.
User must be PRO or higher (or the app must have the "can access owner's video files" capability).
The token must have the video_files scope.
User must be the owner of the API app making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete code that helps me to play the video in android app by using Vimeo networking library

Presenting the final code

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.player);
    // Getting access Token

    String accessToken = getString(R.string.access_token);
    Configuration.Builder configBuilder = new Configuration.Builder(accessToken)
            .enableCertPinning(false);
    //Vimeo Client autenticated

    VimeoClient.initialize(configBuilder.build());
    // the video uri; if you have a video, this is video.uri
```

you should use URI in this format
eg. I use the URI in 2nd format
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789

[image]

```
    final String uri = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789"; 

    VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
    
    @Override
    public void success(Video video) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "Sucessful" + video, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
        ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.files;
        Log.i("TAG1", "videoFiles " + videoFiles);
        if (videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
            VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(0); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
            
            String link = videoFile.getLink();
            Log.i("TAG2", "link " + link);
            // load link
            // use the link to play the video by **EXO Player** or **Video View**
           // Start your video player here
           }
         }

    @Override
    public void failure(VimeoError error) {

        Log.i("TAG3", "vimeo error  : " + error.getErrorMessage());
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "failure due to " + error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
         });
       }
    }
```